# Formula to check if field value is changed and not null in Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, formula, formula-field

I'm adding a formula variable in flows where I need to update a record if Field A is changed and also should not be null. This is a before save flow and runs only on update records. I tried below formula but does not seem to work.

```
ISCHANGED({!$Record.FieldA}) && NOT(ISBLANK({!$Record.FieldA}))
```

What should be changed? I need to check same condition for many fields and hence I am creating a formula field instead of directly updating the conditions.

Comment: What is the data type of this Field A?

Comment: @prem22 Text field

Comment: do you have any other flows that run on this object when you update? Your formula seems to be fine. I tested the formula.

Answer (score 0):

As per @prem22's comment, I was able to reproduce the flow with the information you provided and it did what was required.

1. I used the Account object
2. Triggers on record update
3. When the `PersonMobile` field is changed and not null, update Important Notes (`FinServ__Notes__c`) field with current DateTime:

[image]

I tested both scenarios where the mobile phone is changed to something else as well as when the mobile phone is removed and no other value is provided (thus field is `null` and flow should not trigger).

When it comes to using formulas for checking if a field is null/blank, Salesforce gives you [ISBLANK](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_isblank.htm&type=5) and [ISNULL](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_isnull.htm&type=5), with the preferred one being `ISBLANK` for text fields.

I sometimes have sporadic success with `ISBLANK` and would rather use something more explicit such as `{!$Record.PersonMobilePhone}<>""` which I have found to be more consistent.

I updated my formula used in the entry criteria of my flow to:

`ISCHANGED({!$Record.PersonMobilePhone}) && {!$Record.PersonMobilePhone}<>""`

and I got the same result.

Good luck!